# Plot bubbleplot of entire dataframe with categorical x and y labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe which looks something like this. I would like to plot this dataframe as a bubble map plot. x axis would represent the months (index labels), y would represent the days(column labels) and size of the bubble would be values in the dataframe.

|  | MON | TUE | WED | THU | FRI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JAN | 31 | 84 | 59 | 67 | 13 |
| FEB | 77 | 84 | 74 | 58 | 9 |
| MAR | 39 | 65 | 73 | 97 | 53 |
| APR | 100 | 75 | 63 | 88 | 25 |
| MAY | 60 | 76 | 59 | 21 | 62 |
| JUN | 25 | 18 | 59 | 63 | 91 |
| JUL | 27 | 7 | 65 | 82 | 90 |
| AUG | 55 | 10 | 47 | 82 | 64 |
| SEP | 27 | 55 | 74 | 45 | 88 |
| OCT | 58 | 5 | 42 | 42 | 11 |
| NOV | 74 | 77 | 16 | 1 | 70 |
| DEC | 87 | 13 | 83 | 74 | 57 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reshape your dataframe:

```
df2 = (df.rename_axis('month')
         .reset_index()
         .melt(id_vars=['month'], var_name='day')
       )
```

```
>>> df2.head()
  month  day  value
0   JAN  MON     31
1   FEB  MON     77
2   MAR  MON     39
3   APR  MON    100
4   MAY  MON     60
```

Then, plot using [`seaborn.scatterplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.scatterplot.html):

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.scatterplot(data=df2, x='month', y='day', size='value')
```

[image: seaborn bubbleplot]